# Drag and drop with WPF + Windows Forms

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to use Windows Forms `DataGridView` since it appears the WPF `DataGrid` doesn't allow getting the selection and lacks features like getting the current column and row index.

```
<WindowsFormsHost Name="wfhFileEditorWindow" DockPanel.Dock="Top" AllowDrop="True" >
   <WindowsFormsHost.Child>
      <wf:DataGridView x:Name="dgFileEditorWindow" AllowDrop="True">
      </wf:DataGridView>
   </WindowsFormsHost.Child>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

The problem I have with this workaround is that the element does not appear to accept drag and drop, the cursor turns into a stop sign.

Any suggestion what I need to do to enable dropping onto the `DataGridView`?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this, not sure if it is the "right way" to handle the situation:

```
Private Sub dgFileEditorWindow_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles dgFileEditorWindow.DragEnter
    If (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text)) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    Else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub dgFileEditorWindow_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles dgFileEditorWindow.DragDrop
    Dim filename As String = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString()
    If loadCSVfileToDataGridView(filename, dgFileEditorWindow) Then
        editedFile_Filename = filename
    End If
End Sub
```